# C# Delete assembly.exe.config File

Tags: c#

Strange caveat when I delete my exe.config file in my release folder. When running the application it will recreate it, which is fine, but it also recreates a bunch of DLL files that **use** to be part of the assembly but have no reference them anywhere in the code. Not sure how this is happening. Can anyone shine some light?

**Update:**
Moving the EXE to another machine and running it will cause the same effect to happen. This has nothing to do with running it within Visual Studio's. Cleaning the solution and rebuilding does not help either. Libraries that were removed a year ago will reappear even though they are not referenced anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure they are no longer referenced in the Assembly References of every project?  Try right clicking on your solution and choose Clean Solution, then try again.

Comment: It's re-created when _running_ or when _building_ the app?

Comment: To add to @Mangist's comment, _referenced_ assemblies will still get copied even if you don't use them in code.

Comment: It re-creates when running the application. For example Pex & Moles was removed a year ago, yet returns after deleting exe.config and then running the application. These libraries are no longer referenced in the project, the entire solution was cleaned and rebuilded... still they show up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you delete the App.config file in VS itself rather than deleting the config file from the release directory else VS will rebuild it once the solution/project is rebuilt.

How to setup an end point in code rather than an app.config

```
using System.ServiceModel;

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("[URL to ENDPOINT]");
```

Comment: Ok, create the WCF endpoints in code, rather than relying on an app.config - See answer edit

Comment: I could do this, but doesn't explain the old libraries reappearing when deleting the config file.

Comment: Have you got any references to any external libraries still linked with the solution? Check in the solution explorer under references to see if everything there is what you expect.

Comment: Went through every project, no reference whatsoever. This is why I'm puzzled.

Comment: Which VS are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59129/discussion-between-craig1231-and-bl4kh4k).